# Is it worth adding leaderboards?

Tags: android, google-play, leaderboard

Sure it encourages people to want to "top" other scores, but I feel like it would be flooded with hacked scores. That, and that competition usually exists between people in direct contact. So should I go through the trouble of adding a leaderboard to my game?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you that you do. It's really easy to add leaderboards and achievements in your game using Google Play Services, so this is not a excuse to do it.

You have all related information about leaderboards [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#introduction) and if you're going to work with Android, you can find how implement leaderboards in Android [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with amatellanes.  There's no excuse for adding a leaderboard to your app.  Your size would hardly increase by 600 kb if you have not incorporated play services.  Besides it's free to use. Also people in your Google plus circles are shown separately so that you can compete with them.